# Set PHP variable to MySQL data in foreach loop using array

Tags: php, mysql, variables, foreach

I seem to have looked everywhere for this.

Here is the code i use to set a variable to a piece of data from a MySQL database

```
$PartNo=mysql_result($result,$i,"PartNo");
```

Where

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM PriceList");
```

`$i = 0`, is added to by 1 every time my while loop restarts
  PartNo is a field name in my MySQL table and also the name of the variable I want to set the data in the database to
  PriceList is my database name

I want to loop through all the field names (the array has them) and set variables with the same names to that data. Like this:

```
$PartNo=mysql_result($result,$i,"PartNo");
$Group=mysql_result($result,$i,"Group");
$OnHand=mysql_result($result,$i,"OnHand");
$QOO=mysql_result($result,$i,"QOO");
$Description=mysql_result($result,$i,"Desc");
$Cost=mysql_result($result,$i,"Cost");
```

But with a foreach loop so it isn't as much code.
I was thinking something like this, but it won't execute no matter which way I go about it (parse_str, eval, exec, etc.)

```
$nDatabaseVars=array("PartNo","Group","OnHand","QOO","Desc","Cost");

foreach ($nDatabaseVars as $X) {
    $$X=mysql_result($result,$i,'$X');
}
```

I need "`$$X`" to evaluate out so on the first iteration, it changes to $PartNo= and then sets `$PartNo` to whatever data is in the database on the first line. Which is what this part is: `mysql_result($result,$i,"PartNo")`

If I echo it out instead:

```
foreach ($nDatabaseVars as $X) {
    echo "$$X=mysql_result($result,$i,'$X')";
}
```

I can get it to say exactly what I need executed ($PartNo=mysql_result($result,$i,"PartNo");) but not actually get the variable set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a string containing `"$X"` to `mysql_result`, not the name of your column. Remove the single quotes:

```
$$X=mysql_result($result, $i, $X);
```

Comment: Legends, thank you both. I was looking in the complete wrong spot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$$X=mysql_result($result,$i,'$X'); // these single quotes around $X avoid your actual string to be used.

$$X=mysql_result($result,$i,"$X");
```